# Find out if the if DST is being observed by the machine running SQL

Tags: sql, dst

In C#, I can check TimeZoneInfo.SupportsDaylightSavingTime to find out if the client computer observe DST.  How do I find this out on SQL server?  Specifically, inside a stored procedure.